# Dart : How To add or Subtract Hours and minutes to TimeOfDay

Tags: flutter, dart

The following Line will give the current time

```
TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now(); //12:42
```

I want to add or remove 2 hours and 10 minutes from _time // i.e. 12:52 Or 10:52..etc

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `TimeOfDay` rather than `DateTime`?

Comment: because I am using time picker and time picker returns TimeOfDay

Comment: Then why in the code provided are you calling `TimeOfDay.now()`?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same need, then I checked the source of another [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) on Kotlin and ported their solution as follows:

```
extension TimeOfDayExtension on TimeOfDay {
  // Ported from org.threeten.bp;
  TimeOfDay plusMinutes(int minutes) {
    if (minutes == 0) {
      return this;
    } else {
      int mofd = this.hour * 60 + this.minute;
      int newMofd = ((minutes % 1440) + mofd + 1440) % 1440;
      if (mofd == newMofd) {
        return this;
      } else {
        int newHour = newMofd ~/ 60;
        int newMinute = newMofd % 60;
        return TimeOfDay(hour: newHour, minute: newMinute);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Other solutions do not consider exceeding 60 mins or 24 hours. Trying to add 1 minute to `23:59` will cause a crash. However, this one safely casts it to `00:00`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a extension to add a method for `TimeOfDay`.

```dart
extension TimeOfDayExtension on TimeOfDay {
  TimeOfDay addHour(int hour) {
    return this.replacing(hour: this.hour + hour, minute: this.minute);
  }
}
```

So you can call like `TimeOfDay.now().addHour(2)`

Edt.

You can even improve the method above to be like:

```dart
extension TimeOfDayExtension on TimeOfDay {
  TimeOfDay add({int hour = 0, int minute = 0}) {
    return this.replacing(hour: this.hour + hour, minute: this.minute + minute);
  }
}
```

And you can call: `TimeOfDay.add(hour: 2, minute: 30)`

Comment: Hey Katekko, welcome to StackOverflow! I did some edits to your answer. I highly recommend you to use the formatted code feature of StackOverflow instead of images of code, so others can test your solution more easily.

Comment: @katekko addHour method not work after 11 PM.

Comment: this doesnt handle overflow either, for example, it will error if the current time is something like 9:55am and you use this to add 10 minutes. instead of rolling over to 10:05, it will just crash

Answer (score 8):

If you need this only once and think an extension is too much trouble, you could do this:

```
TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 10)))
```

More eleborate example with timepicker:

```
TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes: 10))),
);
```

Answer (score 8):

**I hope, It will helpful. Based on the need we can change the code**

```
void changeEndTime(TimeOfDay startTimeOfDay) {
    DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    DateTime customDateTime = DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day,
        startTimeOfDay.hour, startTimeOfDay.minute);
    endTimeOfDay =
        TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(customDateTime.add(Duration(minutes: 90)));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TimeOfDay _time = TimeOfDay.now();
```

we can do it like this

```
TimeOfDay newTime = _time.replacing(
        hour: _time.hour - 2,
        minute: _time.minute
      );
```

Comment: From what I can tell this doesn't work if changing across hours, so 00:30 minus 1 hours failed because the hours before less than 0 without doing some logic to see if it's below 0 and changing it back to 23

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using "TimeOfDay.fromDateTime()"
If you want to subtract 2 hours from current Time

TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(hours: 2)));

If you want to add 2 hours to current time

TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 2)));

Answer (score 0):

I wrote another extension maybe a bit more simple. I also keep the overflow at 60 minutes in mind:

```dart
TimeOfDay add({int hours = 0, int minutes = 0}) => TimeOfDay(hour: hour + hours + minutes ~/ 60, minute: minute + minutes % 60);
```

Here `minute` and `hour` are taken from the overriden object like `this.hour` and `this.minute`

Answer (score 0):

Made some modifications on a previous answer to adjust the time when the minutes goes over 60.

You can add this as a separate file in your project, then call the method add from any time of day. Just remember it returns a new TimeOfDay and doesn't modify the existing one.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

extension TimeOfDayExtension on TimeOfDay {
  TimeOfDay add({int hours = 0, int minutes = 0}) => TimeOfDay(
      hour: hour + hours + (minute + minutes) ~/ 60,
      minute: (minute + minutes) % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: solution]

hope you will get help from this

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeOfDay.replacing() //it returns a new TimeOfDay

ex:

```
TimeOfDay currentSlotStart = TimeOfDay.now(); // hours: 12, minutes: 0
TimeOfDay currentSlotEnd = currentSlotStart.replacing(
    minute: currentSlotStart.minute + 30); // Added 30 minutes to it
```